# how to set window location with variable in template builder format

Tags: c#

```
templateBuilder.Append("function link(){\r\n");
templateBuilder.Append("var a =document.getelementById('abc').value;\r\n"); //assume that the value is cc
templateBuilder.Append("window.location=\"/productlist.aspx?wd=");
templateBuilder.Append("\";\r\n");
templateBuilder.Append("}\r\n");
```

from the code above, is anyone able to set my variable "A" join with my window location ?
so there will be >> " /productlist.aspx?wd=cc "

I had tried templateBuilder.Append("window.location=\"/productlist.aspx?wd="+a+"");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like this

```
templateBuilder.Append("function link(){\r\n");
templateBuilder.Append("var a ='/productlist.aspx?wd=' + document.getelementById('abc').value;\r\n"); //assume that the value is cc
templateBuilder.Append("window.location=a");
```

Comment: it's fail to pass the variable a too

Comment: it will convert to wd=%27+%20a

Comment: What's the value you are expecting in "a"?

Comment: a string value from html